# Unable to run e2fsck on partition. Claims the partition is "in use"

Tags: linux, partition, e2fsck

My system claims my partition is in use, but I can't figure out why:

```
root@racknerd-05beb8:~# e2fsck -fvy /dev/vda1
e2fsck 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
/dev/vda1 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

root@racknerd-05beb8:~# mount 
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=483632k,nr_inodes=120908,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=99984k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=99980k,nr_inodes=24995,mode=700)
none on / type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=614400k)

root@racknerd-05beb8:~# df  
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              483632      0    483632   0% /dev
tmpfs              99984    364     99620   1% /run
tmpfs             499908      0    499908   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs              99980      0     99980   0% /run/user/0
none              614400 438456    175944  72% /

root@racknerd-05beb8:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/vda: 12 GiB, 12884901888 bytes, 25165824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcaec3c75

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/vda1        2048 25165823 25163776  12G 83 Linux

root@racknerd-05beb8:~# lsof /dev/vda1
<blank>

root@racknerd-05beb8:~# umount /dev/vda1
umount: /dev/vda1: not mounted.

root@racknerd-05beb8:~# fuser -v /dev/vda1
<blank>

root@racknerd-05beb8:~# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
vda    254:0    0   12G  0 disk 
`-vda1 254:1    0   12G  0 part 

root@racknerd-05beb8:~# lsof -n|grep vda1
jbd2/vda1   298                       root  cwd       DIR               0,39      480          1 /
jbd2/vda1   298                       root  rtd       DIR               0,39      480          1 /
jbd2/vda1   298                       root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/298/exe
```

Comment: Did you booted the system normal?

Comment: Yes, but I have since then created a RAM-drive with a debootstrapped debian system and pivoted to that root, to be able to umount the main drive. Now the plan is to convert the filesystem to btrfs, but I can't do anything on the drive as the system still think it's locked/mounted.

Comment: Ok. Then i have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need either boot the machine with a live cd, because when you normally boot, during boot the drive will get mounted, resulting in this in use error you are getting.
Or use a third party tool to convert the filesystem.
Be careful with converting the filesystem and make sure you have a backup.

Another option would be to clone the disk with clonezilla, and then try to convert the filesystem

Comment: But you can clearly see from my outputs that I have unmounted the partition? The whole problem is that the system is still locking it somewhere and I need to find out where and now to unlock it. Booting with a live cd is not an option.

Comment: Mount the disk on another system as second drive not as boot drive. It's probably the boot drive, which has the boot and maybe efi config. You can't unmount the boot on a running system

Comment: Of course I can. That is the whole purpose if the pivot_root command. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pivot_root.2.html

Comment: If moving the drive to another server was an option, of course I would have done so. In my case, it's not an option. It's the boot drive in this server. I simply created a separate temporary linux-system on a RAM-drive, used pivot_root to move to that temporary RAM system and unmounted the original root drive. The issue is that it's still locked by the system for some reason, but I can't figure out why. All commands I have tried shows that it's not in use and should not be locked.

Comment: Lsblk clearly shows that vda1 still mounted. And it looks like vda1 is your only partition.

Comment: Maybe it's mounted by its uuid. Check with blkid

Comment: lsblk just lists available block devices. Look at the "mountpoint" column and you see that it's blank, thus not mounted.

Comment: And yes, vda1 is the only partition on this system. The root-system is run from RAM-disk.